# Google Collapsible Banner not working in android 9?

Tags: android, ads

Anyone knows about Google Collapsible Banner Ads?

I am facing some issue in load google Collapsible Banner in android 9 device, but it is working fine in android 13 OS devices, I am not sure what was the actual issue is.

Thanks.

Comment: better you share your full code. so anyone can check.

Comment: Thanks for response, it's not much just adding couple of lines

Comment: Bundle extras = new Bundle(); 
extras.putString("collapsible", "top");